# What is the difference between My domain and sites domain?

Tags: community, force.com-sites, custom, custom-domain, mydomain

I have recently started delving into sites and communities. I noticed that I need to have 'sites' domain to play around with communities. I just wanted to know what the difference is and how are they related to each other.

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MyDomain is a custom URL to directly log-in to your Salesforce Instance rather than going through `https//login.Salesforce.com`. You can go through either one to reach your instance, but it allows for custom branding of the log-in experience and also provides a namspace for any Lightning Components in your Org.

A sites Domain is different in that it is a unique domain from which to host a web site (both secure and non-secure) along with any Communities that you might want to build in your organization using sub domains (you can redirect your own web domain to a Sites Domain hosted by Salesforce or register it with Salesforce to use as your Sites Domain). Similar to your org's MyDomain, a Sites domain allows a direct log-in experience that can be custom branded to your organization. The difference being that it is the ONLY way to enter your web site and each of your communities (each community can have a unique log-in URL if you configure it properly).

Both MyDomain and your Sites Domain(s) are registered with ICANN, the governing body that manages web site registrations and IP resolution/redirection across the entire World Wide Web. Salesforce does that for you automatically.