# domain name in our org

Tags: mydomain

I'm trying to create a public site for my organization but I'm asked to register for a domain first. 
[image]

But when i click on my domains from setup, i see the below domain being used already. 
[image]

Can some one tell me what's the difference between the domains used in both scenarios?

Comment: is it published and you are logged in into?

Comment: Check this Post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152953/what-is-the-difference-between-my-domain-and-sites-domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force.com Public Sites require a domain for the public/external deployment. The domain you have registered is your Salesforce "My Domain" which is how you access/login to Salesforce internally.